# Which gender for “I did it” in French?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, genre

In French, if I want to say *I did it*, do I use the masculine *le* or the feminine *la*?

Should I then say *Je l'ai fait* or *Je l'ai faite*?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If “I did it” means that you did something without explicitly stating what, you should use the neutral, thus the masculine

> *Je l'ai fait !*

but if you achieved something, it would be more idiomatic to use

> *J'ai réussi !*

If the thing you did is explicit, then you must use its gender

> *— Et la descente de la Tour Eiffel en snowboard ?
>
>   — Je l'ai faite !*

Comment: So my first guess was the right one. What if by _I did it_ I actually want to say that whatever I had to do, I did (without any implications of having achieved it)? Is my _Je l'ai fait_ OK to use then?

Comment: *Et la descente de la Tour Eiffel en snowboard?*. Même pas cap'! ;)

Comment: @indoxica L'expression populaire "Ce qui est fait n'est plus à faire" indique bien que l'action entreprise est terminée et correctement terminée, sinon on ajoute un adjectif pour préciser pourquoi l'objectif n'a pas été atteint : "Cette passe, je l'ai mal faite, l'adversaire a récupéré le ballon".

Answer (score 4):

Unless there's a known feminine gender behind the *it*, you would use the masculine

> — Tu as remis le rapport?
>   — Oui, je l'ai fait!

But

> — Tu as fait la vaisselle?
>   — Oui, je l'ai faite!

Answer (score 0):

En Français, il y a le pronom relatif. Il évite une répétition dans la même phrase ou la phrase suivante. Ex: '' As-tu fait ton travail ?----- Oui, je L'ai fait !---------Le *L'*est RELATIF au mot travail.---------Si ce pronom relatif est placé avant le verbe  AVOIR ( pas pour le verbe ETRE) le complément s'accorde en genre (masculin ou féminin) et en nombre (singulier ou pluriel)avec le sujet du verbe AVOIR. ----2 Exemples:  ''As-tu pris ton livre?---Oui, je L'ai pris!------As-tu pris tes chaussures? --oui, je *''les''* ai prises !

Comment: Ce c'est pas ça qu'on appelle un pronom relatif. Ici il s'agit simplement d'un pronom objet.